# GDAL Intersection return value

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo

I am using GDAL Intersection to provide me the intersection between 2 maps (I'm running the code in Python 3). My code is working fine and I have good results with it for some months.

Lately, I have run my code for a different city and the intersection map is incomplete. I do not get errors nor warnings, but the only difference is the return value of the Intersection. Normally I get 0 as the return value, but in this case, I get 6 as the return value of the intersection.

I have searched the Intersection in the API page, but I haven't found anything about the return value. I've looked in the following websites:

- [ogr_cookbook](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html?highlight=intersection#calculate-intersection-between-two-geometries)
- [gdal_ogr_layer](https://gdal.org/api/ogrlayer_cpp.html)
- [osgeo_ogr_layer](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Layer-class.html)

```
print(layers['layer_name1'].Intersection(layers['layer_name2'], layers['layer_name3']))
```

When I run this line, I normally get a 0 and I got a correct map and data as the intersection. But now the code returns 6 and I'm trying to figure it out what it means.

Comment: here are the error codes meanings: http://opensme.eu/project/Application/venv/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/error.py

Comment: also https://tutel.me/c/gis/questions/172590/python+gdal+error+6+geos+support+not+enabled